# (General assembly dash - checkpoint 9, project 3) - imported font from google not correctly applied?

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I hope you are all well. I'm taking various tutorials with code etc, and on 'general assembly dash' in the 3rd project, checkpoint 9, it tells you to find a font via google fonts and paste it between the 'head' and 'style' sections of the html code

General assembly dash doesn't seem to like something I've done as it isn't marking the task as complete - please help! (screenshot attached) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJu7a.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer guys!

I had to amend the link google gave me. When I followed Google's steps to get started, I saw that there was some additional text which read "'type=text/css'"

I also had to replace the double speech marks with single speech marks (this tip came from the facebook Q&A group from the general assembly dash webpage

so the new link is displayed as follows:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Shadow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Shadow' rel='stylesheet'>
```

That should do the trick!